# Jar file stopped installing after a number of installation

Tags: java-me, jar, installation

In Samsum DUOS e2252 my .jar file used to install and run properly a few days back but then suddenly it stopped installing while it still gives me option to install and when I click yes it shows processing and after that it says "want to launch application?" and when pressed YES it runs it, but after exiting go to the place where it used to be installed, I don't find installed application there while for each time to run it I have to go to the source file and perform the steps from start, what can be the issue with that? I hope there could be some problem of phone memory or heap.

Note: I have performed soft and hard reset and deleted all the data of phone, but same problem.